# AS3 smooth rotation direction

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm not very good with radial calculations, I can't imagine thus I can't be sure. I need some explanation of Math.atan2() thing, please.

Usual task - to make an object rotate after the mouse. I get the differences, get the angle, I see angles in the text areas and DIRECTLY the object does follow the mouse. What I need now is everything to be smooth. I need angles to be 0-360 but after 180 object rotation becomes -180 and counts backwards, and mouse rotation becomes -90 after 270 and also counts back to 0.

More deeply, I want a smooth rotation, it means a set speed of say 2 per frame, to meet the mouse angle the shortest way. It takes to set conditions and I can't do that cause I don't even understand the logic of these values. They are almost random! I don't need it to be done or copied, I need to understand to move on so if you could please explain how does it work and what I do wrong...

Code is simple:
angle = Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX)/(Math.PI/180) + 90; //+90 cause it lacks it to look at the mouse//
Object01.rotation = angle;

So the problem is I don't even get how it works... if 2 values are different the object can't point at the mouse but it does. Numbers lie and if I need something based on these numbers it will be wrong. Very wrong... Need organization. Meaning I want everything to be ready for further coding that will be based on the rotations to not jump up and down cause of misfit ends.

Add: Explanation of how does it happen, what I described above. Why such a chaos of the values? And an advice on how could I arrange it for further coding, just as I said. Animation alone wont work if I want to make rotation an element of important events such as shooting direction and aiming speed. Or changes of speed rotation of a lockpicked lock. Or anything much more complicated that wont work if I don't make straight and clear values: from A to Z, from 1 to 10, no 8s between 2 and 3, no R before B, no mouse angle 270 when object facing it -90 when they both started from 0 and reached 180 together. 
Oh, and as I said, mouse facing works but when I try to make a certain speed of chasing mouse the shortest way it turns the object wrong directions in all 4 quarters. I assume it's also about this arctangens thing that has issues with delta values becoming negative in different quarters. And when I change it, some other value goes wrong... So I need to know exactly what I'm doing to know what's wrong and how to fix it. So yep. Need explanation. Please.

Add2: angleZ = Math.atan2(oppSide,adjSide)/(Math.PI/180);
So I divided rotation to 4 quarters, for each I count atan as opp. side to adj. side, then add 90, 180 and 270 respectively. My mouse rotation does 360, but the object that follow through simple object.rotation = angleZ; still goes to 180, then from -180 to 0 on the left side. Why does it ignore the simple command? The rotation fits but I need it to be equal, no surprises! Why is it happening? How can a number I directly set to be equal to another number as a base of the action change itself to the one of same rotation but completely different number? It doesn't even know it's degrees! It's as simple as "object.rotation, please be equal to the number I choose!"

Comment: I don't understand what your question is at all. Are you asking for an explanation of that code you supplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just different coordinate systems. Like how x starts at 0 at the left of the stage, goes +x to the right, and -x to the left, object rotation starts at 0˚ pointing up, and goes +180˚ clockwise and -180˚ anti-clockwise.

Math.atan2 happens to start at 0 pointing left (-x), and go +270˚ clockwise and -90˚ anti-clockwise, which is annoying, but it just means you have to convert between coordinate systems by adding 90˚.

You can spin something around over and over of course, so the numbers jump so that they always stay within the same range, because 361˚ is the same as 1˚, and -270˚ is the same as 90˚. You can tell an object to rotate outside of the -180˚ to 180˚ range, and it will normalise the rotation to within those values.

As mitim described, to smoothly animate rotation you'll either need to use `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, a `Timer`, or a tweening library like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). Most tweening libraries can work out the shortest rotation direction for you, but otherwise you can simply calculate both and see which is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, since it seems like you know the angle you need to rotate towards and it's direction, would it be easier to just animate towards that angle to get your smooth rotation? Basically treat it like any other animatable property and just add on your rotation speed (2 degrees it looks like) per frame tick, until it reaches the desired rotation.

1. Find angle amount needed to rotate by
2. Figure out if clockwise or counter clockwise direction and set the rotation amount. This can be figured out by checking if the angle is great then 180 / positive or negative
3. Add the rotation amount * direction every frame tick, until the desired rotation is less then or equal to the rotation amount per frame
4. Set rotation to desired rotation